# How to import my own class that uses an imported module into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a class defined in a file called recording.py that I'm trying to import into a Jupyter notebook. This class makes use of methods from numpy, which I import in both the notebook and the .py file as 'np'. When I try to call one of these methods, I get an error proclaiming that the name 'np' is not defined. I've tried both using 'import recording.py' (and appending the directory it's in to the path) and running '%run recording.py' in a cell, and I get the same error. What am I missing here? I can't think of anything else to try.

EDIT for additional clarity:

I have a file recording.py that defines a class:

```
import numpy as np
class Recording:
--- some methods ---
```

where methods from numpy are used in some of the class methods. In the same directory, I have a Jupyter notebook where I want to use this class. In this notebook, I have:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/file')
import recording #or from recording import Recording
r = recording.Recording(initialization arguments)
r.method_that_uses_numpy()
```

I have also tried replacing 'import recording' with '%run recording.py'. When I try to execute this, I get this error asserting that 'np' is not defined:

```
/Documents/neuroscience/scratch/recording.py in remove_neuron(self, n)
     41 
     42     def remove_neuron(self,n):
---> 43         self.centroid = np.delete(self.centroid,n,1)
     44         self.time = np.delete(self.time,n,1)
     45         self.intRaw = np.delete(self.intRaw,n,1)

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried so far and error you are getting?

Comment: did you try `sys.path.append("path to file")` ?

Comment: Have you "restart and run all"?

Comment: Restarting everything seems to work, but I don't have any intuition for why there should have been any problem in the first place, which gives me no confidence that it won't happen again. The code I'm working on in this notebook is performing a fit to a large dataset and takes a while to run. Restarting isn't a viable solution if this becomes a chronic problem.